Prometheus on Nginx Server Blocks (Virtual Hosts)
The setup:

Nginx: Single instance hosting 3 websites using server blocks.
Prometheus: Monitoring tool to gather metrics.
Goal: Monitor the performance of each individual website.

I want to collect data on 3 websites hosted on a single Nginx with Prometheus
By adding the stub_status on the nginx default file and installing ngnix-exporter,
I am able to collect metrics for all the traffic on the Nginx
However, I need to collect data for each website/server block
sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

<
<
server {
    listen 8080;
    # Optionally: allow access only from localhost
    # listen localhost:80;

    location = /stub_status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
    }
}

